# Regex to match all occurences of dots within enclosing dollar signs

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace all dots in a string which are enclosed by dollar signs.
There is no nested structure so I think regular expressions are the right tool for this.

An example string looks like this:

```
asdf $asdf.asdf.$ $..asdf$
```

The regex I came up with matches the part within the dollar signs, but I want a match for each dot within the dollar signs [(example)](https://regex101.com/r/yH0fE8/2):

```
\$([^$]*)\$
```

so for the example string it should yield four matches.  How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Or better, what is the programming language?

Comment: Try [`(?:\$(?!(?:[^$]*\$[^$]*\$)*[^$]*$)|(?!^)\G)[^$.]*\K\.`](https://regex101.com/r/vD1fE4/2) if it is PCRE.

Comment: The programming language is python, But i could use the pcre module, so that your expression would work as well, i think.

Comment: Well, if it is Python, the solution is much simpler, I will post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Python, the easiest solution is to use your pattern to match the substrings from `$` to `$`, and replace `.` with anything you want with a lambda:

```
import re
s = "a.sdf $asdf.asdf.$. . .$..asdf$"
r = re.compile(r'\$([^$]*)\$')
print(r.sub(lambda m: m.group().replace('.',''), s))
# => a.sdf $asdfasdf$. . .$asdf$
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Bz1rgU)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be very hard with a regex, since you have to count the dollar signs in some sense (you want only to call every second gap between two dollar signs "enclosed", and the others "outside" right?)

So it seems easier to (python example)

- do a `mystring.split('$')`, which gives you a list
- then take every second item, e.g. `newlist = oldlist[1::2]`
- count the dots (`''.join(newlist).count('.')`)